# Como criar uma query com union utilizando NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou necessitando implementar uma `query` em [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate) que faça um `union` entre 2 tabelas. Em [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), seria algo assim:

```sql
SELECT T1.Id AS ID
FROM TABELA1 AS T1
UNION    
SELECT T2.Id AS ID
FROM TABELA2 AS T2
```

Não encontrei nenhuma forma de fazer um `union`, nem com `QueryOver`, e nem com `Linq`.

> Alguém conhecer algo que possa me ajudar?

**Edit 1**

Com `Linq` até cheguei a uma "quase" solução, mais ocorreu um erro dizendo que `Union` não é suportado por [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate). O que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

```c#
var query = (from t1 in Session.Query<Tabela1>()
             select t1.Id
             ).Union(from t2 in Session.Query<Tabela2>()
                     select t2.Id);
query.ToList();
```

O erro foi o seguinte:

> The UnionResultOperator result operator is not current supported

Nem sei qual caminho buscar agora, talvez terei que fazer os 2 `selects` separados e o `union` em memória.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tiver controle sobre o banco de dados, poderia **criar uma view no banco de dados, que faça o union**, e depois mapear uma classe sua para a view. Isso resolveria o problema.

Se não for dessa forma, acho que só fazendo em memória mesmo.

Segundo [essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597505/195417), é possível usar o método `Future` para fazer duas queries na mesma chamada ao banco, o que seria melhor do que fazer duas chamadas distintas. Ainda assim, todos os resultados seriam retornados, **sem eliminar duplicatas, o que teria de ser feito em memória**.

```
var resultSet1 = this.Session.CreateCriteria<A>().Future<A>();
var resultSet2 = this.Session.CreateCriteria<B>().Future<B>();
```

Infelizmente, segundo essa [outra resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5225939/195417), não é possível usar `Future` com o LINQ, até a versão 3, então parece que a única forma no momento é usar a sintaxe acima.

Comment: Sim eu já vi algumas pessoas fazendo isso, mais eu to construindo um web service, para controlar sincronização dos dados locais (sistema legado) com um sistema de vendas remoto (offline), e to necessitando desse `union` para a consulta de itens deletados ou desativos no sistema. E assim tenho 2 consultas, uma para deletados em uma tabela de auditoria, que guarda os identificadores dos registros deletados, por período, e outra para os registros marcados com um flag do banco de dados de inativo, também filtrados por período. Então essa consulta será para uma grande quantidade de entidades.

Comment: Estou testando o caso de fazer em memória seguindo [essa questão do SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623146/sql-union-to-nhibernate-criteria), na resposta aceita. Fiz um exemplo aqui e aparentemente está funcionando perfeitamente, mais mesmo assim seria melhor fazer direto na base de dados. Mas toda dica para melhorar é bem vinda. Vou dar uma olha na dica que você passou e ver se é melhor para meu caso.